# oracle where clause is not working with sysdate

Tags: oracle, where-clause, sysdate

Please help me,
DAY_ID is database field which contains 1-7 number. 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday and so on.

```
DECLARE
V_DAY_ID NUMBER(1) :=0;
BEGIN
SELECT DAY_ID INTO V_DAY_ID FROM DAYS WHERE DAY_NAME = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY');
END;
```

This query is not working please help...

Comment: `DAY`is padded. Have you try with `LIKE`? And also check `NLS` and table content. If you have it with different country will have days with different names.

Comment: yes sir, I have also tried with LIKE QUERY but it is not working

Comment: What's DAY_ID and DAY_NAME  column types?  what's the error?

Comment: DAY is a table name where 2 columns (Day_id, Day_name) like (1, 'Monday'), (2,'Tuesday), (3,'Wednesday) ----- (7,'Sunday)

Comment: You should include the table strcutue and data as part of the question, as formatted text (not images); and copied and pasted rather than retyping it so we see exactly what you really have.

Comment: If one of the answers is right for you, please accept it; this is both a way to mark the question as closed and to say thanks to people who helped you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.

Answer (score 5):

By default Oracle pads day names up to the longest in the session date language (so 9 in English). You can override that [with the `FM` modifer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA).

You also need to match the case, and with the values you showed [you need `Day`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-4EF054FF-9996-4637-8476-136FC7A8246D) (which gives e.g. 'Sunday') rather than `DAY` ('SUNDAY'):

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMDay')
```

or if the values are actually uppercase (you've shown both!):

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMDAY')
```

But you also shouldn't assume that whoever calls this is using English in their session, specify that you want the English day name to make sure it matches what is in your table:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMDAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''')
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9d38/1)

The format models [are described in thee documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-4EF054FF-9996-4637-8476-136FC7A8246D).

Comment: Thank you. It is working perfectly.. Can you explain it further, what the difference b/w DAY and FMday

Comment: @SYEDZEESHANALI - I've add an example and some links to the documentation. But `DAY` gives you `'SUNDAY   '` which is uppercase and padded, `FMDay` gives you `'Sunday'` which is mixed case and not padded.

Answer (score 1):

Your DAY_NAME isn't saved with uppercase, so in the condition add [UPPER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions206.htm) function (and TRIM value to ignore spaces)

```
DECLARE
V_DAY_ID NUMBER(1) :=0;
BEGIN
SELECT DAY_ID INTO V_DAY_ID FROM DAYS WHERE UPPER(DAY_NAME) = TRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY'));
END;
```

Comment: Sir, it is already saved in Upper Case. I have checked this query but same error..

Comment: @SYEDZEESHANALI in your comments it's not uppercase, what's the error?

Comment: select * from days;

DAY_ID DAY_NAME
------ ----------
     1 MONDAY
     2 TUESDAY
     3 WEDNESDAY
     4 THURSDAY
     5 FRIDAY
     6 SATURDAY
     7 SUNDAY

Comment: It is showing 2 different error....   ORA-01403: no data found                                         
ORA-06512: at line 4

Comment: when i am applying this query. It is working, I don't need this query                                            SELECT DAY_ID INTO V_DAY_ID FROM DAYS WHERE DAY_NAME = 'SUNDAY';